# Javascript document element in rails layout file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a web application using rails. I have individual `html.erb` files where I run `script.js` on each file. I want to follow DRY so I want to put `script.js` in my layout's file instead of each individual view file.

Here is `script.js`:

```
if(document.documentElement.clientWidth < 570) {
  //do some stuff
}
```

This works fine when I put it in each of my view individually but doesn't work when I only put it in my layouts file. I have a feeling that this is because I am using `document`. If this is true I'm not sure what I should replace `document` with. If this is not true then I'm not sure what is wrong.

If you could help me understand why `script.js` doesn't work when I put it in the layouts file that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do:

Put you files in:

`lib/assets/javascript`
or put your file in
`vendors/assets/javascript`

After that load the file in application.js
`//=require script.js`

In script.js, you can add conditions if you want to run the script only for few pages.
You can check for example if a div exists into your html page

```
if ($('#mydiv').length){
  //do something
}
```

If you are using turbolinks, the situation will change, you will need to do more things:
You can install jquery-turbolinks and have your methods in a function

```
$(document).ready(function () { /* ... */ });
```

Comment: Yup I ended up using jquery-turbolinks `ready` callback. Thanks!